# Scheduled Messages at set repeated intervals

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have the following tasks within a Spring-Boot/JPA domain:

```
id: 1, task: GET:http://example.com/file.zip, schedule: every-minute
id: 2, task: DELETE:/some/path, schedule: every-5-minutes
id: 2, task: TOUCH:/some/path, schedule: every-1-hour
```

I have a spring service called `taskHandlerService` that is capable of handling the above tasks,
But I have been wondering how to schedule them so that the messages reach the `taskHandlerService` at those specified intervals.

The task list changes frequently, so these jobs don't run for long.

A naive approach I could think of here would be to create multiple Quartz-jobs, one for each task on the list and then the job would take care of calling the method on the `taskHandlerService` with the message as the argument.

Is there a better approach to solve this problem?

update: After a bit of searching, a delayed queue seems like a better approach. But not sure how to convert the Qaurtz Cron Schedule expression into that queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark method with `@Scheduled` annotation and Spring will care about creating timers etc.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: The message list is stored on the table and is not static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use those annotation to your methods :

```
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * ? * *") // for the first method
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 */5 * ? * *") //Second method
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * ? * *")   // third method
```

for more information you can check an example [HERE](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: The message list is stored on the table and is not static.